# IE settimeout loses event variable

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, settimeout

This seems to work fine in Firefox but, in IE8 specifically (it may work in other version of IE), I have an issue where the event variable is lost.

There is an event (mousedown) that calls a function that stores a parameter set. One of the parameters is the event itself. The function that is called stores the parameters in global variables so they can be accessed by the function called in the settimeout.

Once it is executed, the function called by the set timeout no longer has access to the properties in the event variable. It is still recognized as an event object, but all the properties are reset.

I have tried using function references, using anonymous functions both using the globals and also passing them as parameters but nothing seems to be working. Any one have any ideas?

I know this is a little complicated so I setup a simple example that shows my issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fd8sk/

When you click 'Fire now' (which doesn't use a settimeout), you get that the button click is a number. When you click the 'Fire delay', the button is now 'Unknown'.

This is a pretty generic function that has a lot of parameters that aren't always used so I'm hoping to avoid major refactoring of this. In my real example, the parameter that is the event in my issue case won't be an event in other scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onmousedown="eventFired(event);"
```

does something subtly different in the event model of IE<9 than it does in other browsers.

In most browsers, the above works because `onX` inline event handlers receive an implicit argument-like local variable called `event`, which is a newly-minted `Event` object for each new event. This gets passed to the `eventFired` function and remembered for later use.

In the legacy-IE event model, there aren't separate event objects, only the `window.event` property, which there's only ever one of, one which returns details of the current event being handled. When you refer to `event` in an inline event handler attribute, you're getting that property as a global variable, and not a newly-spawned instance as a local argument. This gets passed to the function and remembered, but only the object is remembered and not its values. Later on, when the object is re-used, its properties reflect the new event being handled (if any), not the old.

So remember only the particular property value you're interested in keeping instead of the `event` object. I'd also avoid using inline event handler attributes as there are so many gotchas with them.

```
<input type="button" id="fire-now" value="Fire now" />
<input type="button" id="fire-delay" value="Fire delay" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('fire-now').onclick= function(e) {
        e= e || window.event;
        alert(event.button);
    };
    document.getElementById('fire-delay').onclick= function(e) {
        e= e || window.event;
        var button= e.button;
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(button);
        }, 1000);
    };
</script>
```

Note that this isn't the end of your cross-browser worries as IE<9's `button` property has [different values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the standard [MouseEvent buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!

Comment: Actually, the 2 solutions I had come up with were the ones that you and @epascarello suggested. I just wanted to post it here to see if there was a better/easier solution. I didn't have the reason behind it, though. I appreciate the write up. Since it's a generic function, I think I will end up passing the property I need as suggested here. The cloning would affect a lot more code in my situation which is less appealing.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not pass events, you have to look at the `window.event`. Plus you can not store a reference to the event object in IE. You need to copy the properties you want to use of it and store it in a new object.

Comment: Passing the event actually is working in IE as demonstrated in the example (at least in IE8). We have tried to check the window.event in the delayed function but the event is still cleared so it ends up being null.

Comment: ah, only reason it works is the fact you are using event in a global sense. If you attach your code in a unobtrusive way `elemenObject.click=eventFired`, it would have been broken.